# How do I install Java? I can't figure it out

Tags: java

I want to play Java games on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Laptop. I have looked at many tutorials across the web and keep getting confused and hitting error messages. Please help. (Former Windows User)

Comment: Please edit your question to clearly explain exactly what you have tried and the complete, exact error messages that resulted. The details matter a lot.

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: I can't do anything because of this message

Comment: Next time, look just a little harder: http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process

Answer (score 1):

You can install java from the commandline with:

```
$ sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```

You can get to a terminal commandline by hitting this keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

The **$** you see in the commanline is the prompt you see when your enter the terminal mode.  Type in the text the follows and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use Oracle's Java, you can install it with a PPA. First open a terminal by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

The first command adds the PPA so you are able to download Java. The second command 'refreshes' or 're-syncs' the avaliable packages. The last one installs Oracle's Java, version 8.

After it has installed, you can check by running:

```
java -version
```

Comment: Please use the `{}` button in the editor for multiline terminal commands, and surround keys with `<kbd>` and `</kbd>`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to install Oracle's Java. Here are the steps:

Open a terminal with `CTRL + ALT + T`, or just type `terminal` in dash.

Then start typing . . .

**1) First add the PPA**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

**2) Update your repositories**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**3) Install Java version of your preference**

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
```

If you prefer to install another Java version, just change "8" to your desired version, for example, if you want to install Java 6 just type this: `sudo apt install oracle-java6-installer`

**4) Mark Java version as default (if you installed Java 8)**

```
sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default
```

In this link you can find more information about:
http://tipsonubuntu.com/2016/07/31/install-oracle-java-8-9-ubuntu-16-04-linux-mint-18/

Comment: After doing your third step, a EULA came up, and when I click OK nothing happens

Comment: You have to press Tab until it highlights the OK, then press Enter.